# Part of -ffast-math (FTZ, DAZ) is disabled when using optimization (GCC)

Tags: c, math, gcc, optimization

The gcc flag `-funsafe-math-optimizations` (part of `-ffast-math`) turns on `FTZ` and `DAZ` (flush-to-zero and denormals-are-zero). However, turning on optimization disables this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    //_MM_SET_DENORMALS_ZERO_MODE(_MM_DENORMALS_ZERO_ON);
    float normal_f = 1.18e-38f;
    double normal_d = 2.23e-308;

    normal_f *= 0.1f;
    if (normal_f != 0.0f) 
        printf("FTZ/DAZ disabled for floats (%e)\n", (double) normal_f);
    normal_d *= 0.1;
    if (normal_d != 0.0)
        printf("FTZ/DAZ disabled for doubles (%e)\n", normal_d);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc foo.c -ffast-math` both FTZ and DAZ are enabled (i.e., no output to stdout). However, if including any optimization (e.g., `-O1`, `-O3`, `-Ofast`) then FTZ and DAZ are disabled:

```
$ ./a.out 
FTZ/DAZ disabled for floats (1.180000e-39)
FTZ/DAZ disabled for doubles (2.230000e-309)
```

Even stranger, I see the same behavior when I explicitly enable FTZ and DAZ with `_MM_SET_DENORMALS_ZERO_MODE(_MM_DENORMALS_ZERO_ON)`. Optimization disables it. This command only changes anything when compiling without -ffast-math.

My question: how do I achieve FTZ/DAZ when using optimization? Also, are there other -ffast-math behaviors that are disabled with optimization?

I have observed this in both gcc 10.2 and 6.3

Comment: @njuffa Yes, I tried that in many combinations. No matter where I put the `-O` it clobbers the FTZ/DAZ. And beyond command line switch order, explicitly setting FTZ/DAZ with intrinsics is overridden by optimizations

Comment: The compiler is probably constant-folding everything with optimizations enabled and will also evaluate the branch at compile-time. There is no reason for the compiler to perform the optimization at compile-time. The flag is for optimization purposes. I don't think it makes no guarantee that the behavior will be different. It merely allows the compiler to give further possible outputs if optimization may benefit from it.

Comment: And when using an instruction such as `_MM_SET_DENORMALS_ZERO_MODE(_MM_DENORMALS_ZERO_ON)` it is generally impossible for the compiler to know while constant-folding. That would in general require actually executing the program.

Comment: @user17732522 Can you post this as an answer? That turns out to be the case. I'll post a self-answer in a minute but will give you the answer credit

Comment: @aquilonis Feel free to post it as an answer yourself. I was just making guesses, I haven't verified this to be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this behavior is an artifact of my unit tests. The compiler itself doesn't obey FTZ/DAZ, only the generated code does. As a result, in a situation like exampled here the compiler performs calculations and knows that it's safe to bypass the conditional statements and move straight to the printfs.

Breaking this into 2 compile units, the problem disappears:

bar.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check_normalf(float f)
{
    if (f != 0.0f)  {
        printf("FTZ/DAZ disabled for floats (%e)\n", (double) f);
    }
}

void check_normal(float d)
{
    if (d != 0.0)  {
        printf("FTZ/DAZ disabled for doubles (%e)\n", d);
    }
}
```

foo.c

```
#include <pmmintrin.h>

void check_normalf(float f);
void check_normal(float d);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    //_MM_SET_DENORMALS_ZERO_MODE(_MM_DENORMALS_ZERO_ON);
    float normal_f = 1.18e-38f;
    double normal_d = 2.23e-308;
    check_normalf(normal_f * 0.1f);
    check_normal(normal_d * 0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem persists when the check functions are part of the same file, but that's again the compiler optimizations.